# Issues with TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Anyone notice this?
In my mobile air application, when I have text in a field and I tap on the text field, the pointer will sometimes shift a few words behind if I  hit backspace or try to type in words. It shows itself at the end but then it shifts off and assumes I'm injecting characters in between chars instead of at the end.

Normal stage, normal situations. Adobe air 23 with a target android sdk of 22. Haven't tested on iOS

Comment: yes it was my problem too, i can remember slightly, may you have to try **Text Layout Framework** (TLF) which is deprecated but should works

Answer (score 0):

First, update your AIR application by linking with the latest Flex SDK: use the latest Apache Flex SDK, not the Adobe Flex SDK, since the Adobe version contains many bugs in text input fields implementation, that have been patched by the Apache Flex community.

Note that most of the code that deals with text fields is not implemented in the AIR runtime but in the Flex libraries that come with the application.

Then, disable any virtual keyboard on your Android device, like the SwiftKey Keyboard extension, since those keyboards have bad behaviours when interacting with AIR/Flex applications.